# Azure DevOps - How to create build pipeline NOT triggered by Tags

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

Is there a way to create a branch pipeline trigger that does not trigger when a TAG is created? I want that all commits to the master branch trigger the pipeline, but i'm also using TAGs to trigger Nuget packaging! and I don't want these mixed up...

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It would be to use the `exclude` on the trigger under tags:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: string  # identifier (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscore)
    type: enum  # see the following "Type" topic
    name: string  # repository name (format depends on `type`)
    ref: string  # ref name to use; defaults to 'refs/heads/master'
    endpoint: string  # name of the service connection to use (for types that aren't Azure Repos)
    trigger:  # CI trigger for this repository, no CI trigger if skipped (only works for Azure Repos)
      branches:
        include: [ string ] # branch names which will trigger a build
        exclude: [ string ] # branch names which will not
      tags:
        include: [ string ] # tag names which will trigger a build
        exclude: [ string ] # tag names which will not
      paths:
        include: [ string ] # file paths which must match to trigger a build
        exclude: [ string ] # file paths which will not trigger a build
```

Taken from [YAML schema documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to create a branch pipeline trigger that does not trigger when a TAG is created?

The answer is yes, we could use the [Push trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#push-trigger) with `exclude` clause for branch and tag trigger.

```
trigger: 
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  tags:
    exclude:
    - TAG
```

**Note:**

- If you specify an `exclude` clause without an `include` clause for `branches`, `tags`, or `paths`, it is equivalent to specifying `*` in the `include` clause.
- To exclude multiple tags about TAG, we could use Wildcard with tag, like `TAG**`.